# Parse request response for key, value pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm storing the response from a POST request to Instagram's API into a text file. What's contained in this response is HTML, which includes an access token I'd like to dig out. The reason it's HTML is because this POST response is really meant to be dealt with by the end user, wherein they click a button and are then provided with the access code. However I need to do this on the backend, hence needing to deal with the HTML response.

In any event, here's my code so far (real client ID is obscured for this post obviously):

```
OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e65f&redirect_uri=https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code"
OAuth_AccessRequest = requests.post(OAuthURL).text 
#print OAuth_AccessRequest

with open('response.txt', 'w') as OAuthResponse:
        OAuthResponse.write(OAuth_AccessRequest.encode("UTF-8"))

OAuthReady = open('response.txt', 'r')
OAuthView = OAuthReady.read()
print OAuthView
```

What I'm left with after this is HTML stored in a text file. Among the HTML however are dictionaries, which I need to access the value, pairs for — some of it, for example, looks like this:

```
</div> <!-- .root -->

    <script src=//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/422f3d9/scripts/polyfills/es5-shim.min.js></script>
<script src=//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/bluebar/422f3d9/scripts/polyfills/es5-sham.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"static_root":"\/\/instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/bluebar\/422f3d9","entry_data":{},"hostname":"instagram.com","platform":{"is_touch":false,"app_platform":"web"},"qe":{"su":false},"display_properties_server_guess":{"viewport_width":360,"pixel_ratio":1.5},"country_code":"US","language_code":"en","gatekeepers":{"tr":false},"config":{"dismiss_app_install_banner_until":null,"viewer":null,"csrf_token":"2aedabf96ad1fe86fab0"},"environment_switcher_visible_server_guess":true};</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

It's the string of numbers that is the value for the key "csfr_token" that I need to grab. What's the best approach for digging this out of the HTML that's stored in the txt file?

Comment: those aren't dictionaries. Those are [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: `print(re.search('"csrf_token":(.*?)\}',s).group(1))`, use BeautifulSoup to get the script tags and extract the csrf with the regex

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: it is a JavaScript object definitions that happens to be parseable as JSON. That's not always a safe assumption however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks Martijn, just to be clear: those JS object definitions can't be handled like dictionaries, correct? They looked like key, value pairs to me :)

Comment: @Malvin9000: you can grab the whole string and pass it to `json.loads()` to return a Python dictionary. Note the lowercase `false` and `true`  values, for example, those are Javascript or JSON booleans, not Python syntax. And the `null` would be `None` in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `csrf_token` string is the only such string in the whole page, it'll be trivial to extract it with a regular expression:

```
import re

token_pattern = re.compile(r'"csrf_token":\s*"([^"]+)"')

token = token_pattern.search(requests.post(OAuthURL).content).group(1)
```

Note that I used the *`content`* attribute of the response, there is no point in decoding the whole response to Unicode when all you need is a few ASCII characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import requests, re
>>> token_pattern = re.compile(r'"csrf_token":\s*"([^"]+)"')
>>> OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e65f&redirect_uri=https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code"
>>> token_pattern.search(requests.post(OAuthURL).content).group(1)
'3fd6022ac344c3eaea46e87e258ef9c6'
```

You may want to look at the *headers and cookies* of the response as well; a CSRF token is usually also set as a cookie (or at the very least as a value in the session).

For this specific request for example, the token is also stored as a cookie, matching the value in the JavaScript block:

```
>>> r = requests.post(OAuthURL)
>>> r.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='csrftoken', value='b2b621c198642e26a19fc9bf1b38d246', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='instagram.com', domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1467828030, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>
>>> r.cookies['csrftoken']
'b2b621c198642e26a19fc9bf1b38d246'
>>> 'b2b621c198642e26a19fc9bf1b38d246' in r.content
True
>>> token_pattern.search(r.content).group(1)
'b2b621c198642e26a19fc9bf1b38d246'
```

Comment: @Malvin9000: the response object has `.headers` and `.cookies` attributes.

Comment: @Malvin9000: in fact, I should have looked; there is a cookie right there.

Comment: Strangely, the token in the cookie is not the csrftoken that I need. When I print out the token string in r.cookies['csrftoken'] it's totally different from the token values for csrfmiddlewaretoken and csrftoken.

Comment: @Malvin9000 are you sure you didn't create separate requests? In my testing the cookie matches the content returned each time. But make sure you use that same cookie when sending your next request! Use a `requests.Session()` object to handle cookies (they'll be automatically sent to the server with each request).

Comment: Thanks again Martijn, appreciate the help. For some reason, the only csrftoken that works with the next step in the OAuth procedure is when I grab it from the URL that's created when I paste the AOuthURL into a browser. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the `(r'"csrf_token":\s*"([^"]+)"')` part of the line `token_pattern = re.compile(r'"csrf_token":\s*"([^"]+)"')` is working?

Comment: Are you sure it is the CSRF token you need? That's a *Cross Site Request Forgery* token, used to prevent hijacking of existing sessions by a third party. They play a role in form submission, but **not** in OAuth authentication.

Comment: In other words the token is needed to submit the form in the page and the server gives you the OAuth token after successful submission.

Comment: Well...that would explain it :\ This is what I need to do: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308061/retrieve-oauth-code-in-redirect-url-provided-as-post-response) - I have to figure out a way to grab the token that appears at the end of the redirect URL. I thought response history would work for that, but no luck.

Comment: By the way, I don't quite appreciate the accept-unaccept-accept-unaccept flip flopping here. I did after all answer *the stated question* even if you may have misunderstood what you got from it. :-)

Comment: My apologies for the answer accepting issue, I going back and forth between the app and desktop, screw up on my part I must have clicked it accidentally too many times on the app.

Comment: I don't have time right now to analyse the form here, but I suspect you need to do a GET first, extract the CSRF token, do a POST for the form parameters and include the token, and *then* the server will redirect and give you a OAuth token.

Comment: It's okay; thanks for stabilising the state :-) It appeared as if every time you discovered you weren't yet at your end goal (successful OAuth authorization) you unaccepted my answer. :-)

Comment: Whoops, my bad, sorry about :\ I was actually walking in the rain with my iPhone and obsessively checking this post for your comment responses, touchscreens aren't good with water on them!