# Retrieve OAuth code in redirect URL provided as POST response

Tags: python, python-2.7, post, request

Python newbie here, so I'm sure this is a trivial challenge...

Using Requests module to make a POST request to the Instagram API in order to obtain a code which is used later in the OAuth process to get an access token. The code is usually accessed on the client-side as it's provided at the end of the redirect URL.

I have tried using [Request's response history method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.history), like this (client ID is altered for this post):

```
OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e67355f&redirect_uri=https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code"
OAuth_AccessRequest = requests.post(OAuthURL)
ResHistory = OAuth_AccessRequest.history
for resp in ResHistory:
    print resp.status_code, resp.url
print OAuth_AccessRequest.status_code, OAuth_AccessRequest.url
```

But the URLs this returns are not revealing the code number string, instead, the redirect just looks like this:

```
302 https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e67355f&redirect_uri=https://www.dashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code
200 https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%cb0096f08a3848e67355f%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened%26response_type%3Dcode
```

Where if you do this on the client side, using a browser, `code` would be replaced with the actual number string.

Is there a method or approach I can add to the POST request that will allow me to have access to the actual redirect URL string that appears in the web browser?

Answer (score 2):

It should work in a browser if you are already logged in at Instagram. If you are not logged in you are redirected to a login page:

```
https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3Dcb0096f08a3848e67355f%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened%26response_type%3Dcode
```

Your Python client is not logged in and so it is also redirected to Instagram's login page as shown by the value of `OAuth_AccessRequest.url` :

```
>>> import requests
>>> OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e67355f&redirect_uri=https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code"
>>> OAuth_AccessRequest = requests.get(OAuthURL)
>>> OAuth_AccessRequest
<Response [200]>
>>> OAuth_AccessRequest.url
u'https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3Dcb0096f08a3848e67355f%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened%26response_type%3Dcode'
```

So, to get to the next step, your Python client needs to login. This requires that the client extract and set fields to be posted back to the same URL. It also requires cookies and that the `Referer` header be properly set. There is a hidden CSRF token that must be extracted from the page (you could use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for example), and form fields `username` and `password` must be set. So you would do something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e67355f&redirect_uri=https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code"
session = requests.session()    # use session to handle cookies
OAuth_AccessRequest = session.get(OAuthURL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(OAuth_AccessRequest.content)
form = soup.form
login_data = {form.input.attrs['name'] : form.input['value']}
login_data.update({'username': 'your username', 'password': 'your password'})
headers = {'Referer': OAuth_AccessRequest.url}
login_url = 'https://instagram.com{}'.format(form.attrs['action'])
r = session.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=headers)

>>> r
<Response [400]>
>>> r.json()
{u'error_type': u'OAuthException', u'code': 400, u'error_message': u'Invalid Client ID'}
```

Which looks like it will work once provided a valid client ID.

As an alternative, you could look at [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) which will handle the form submission for you, including the hidden CSRF field:

```
import mechanize

OAuthURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=cb0096f08a3848e67355f&redirect_uri=https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened&response_type=code"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(OAuthURL)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['username'] = 'your username'
br.form['password'] = 'your password'
r = br.submit()
response = r.read()
```

But this doesn't work because the referer header is not being set, however, you could use this method if you can figure out a solution to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your informative response! When I try your first approach, I do get a 200 response but when I try `print r.text` nothing actually prints out, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. You should be getting another HTML form asking to confirm access - that's what I get in Python and in browser. Once you have that, you need to extract the form field for `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and post back to the form target with the `allow` field set to `Authorize`. What happens when you try it in your browser?

Comment: When I paste the first URL (stored in OAuthURL) into my browser, if I'm already logged into Instagram, it immediately redirects to the redirect URL with access code at the end of the new URL.

Comment: That's because you have already logged in and your browser holds a session cookie, and because you have also authorized the third-party application in Instagram (which you need only do once). From Python it's the same: once you have authorized the application you should only need to login again. Possibly you are seeing an empty `r.text` because `https://www.smashboarddashboard.com/whathappened` returns an empty body, but I can't tell because the server rejects requests to that URL.

Comment: Is there a way, using Requests to package the cookie data into a payload or something to make the final Post request? Using HTTP header browser plugin, I can see all the info in the cookie, perhaps I can collect that and make the second call.